# How to check if a file descriptor has any data available?

Tags: c, posix

I'd like to know if a fd has data available for reading. I have tried `ioctl` with `FIONREAD` but that results in a "Operation not supported error". Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select()`, with a zero (not `NULL`) timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Use `poll()` or `select()` on your file descriptor.